# Convert/ wrap async listener to Observable (RxJava2)

Tags: android, rx-java2, listeners

I want to wrap a real listener to Observable object.
For starters here is a test case, with him everything is fine.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getObservablePhoneState()
        // Run on a background thread
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        // Be notified on the main thread
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(integer -> Log.i(TAG, "----- subscribe onNext = " + integer));
}

private Flowable<Integer> getObservablePhoneState() {
    return Flowable.create(emitter -> {

        Log.i(TAG, "Emitting 1");
        emitter.onNext(1);

        Log.i(TAG, "Emitting 2");
        emitter.onNext(2);

    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
}



*** logcat ***
Emitting 1
Emitting 2
----- subscribe onNext = 1
----- subscribe onNext = 2
```

This code generates an error:

```
private Flowable<Integer> getObservablePhoneState() {
    return Flowable.create(emitter -> {

        PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onCallStateChanged = " + state);
                emitter.onNext(state);
            }
        };
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
}

*** logcat ***
io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: 
Attempt to read from field 'android.os.MessageQueue 
android.os.Looper.mQueue' on a null object reference
```

With Observable.create() the same error.
Perhaps this is due to the fact that [RxJava2 does not support emitting a null value](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0).

**How to do it right?**

Comment: Is it possible you're calling thing before onCreate() in your activity?  I tried your code and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` to avoid creating the `PhoneStateListener` in a different thread, because under the hood is trying to send messages using a Handler which mQueue is null. Just call

```
getObservablePhoneState()
     .subscribe { integer -> Log.i("", "----- subscribe onNext = " + integer) }
```

Comment: Thx, your comment was useful. the code worked. but...
onNext occurs only 1--3 times, and further - nothing. I'm testing under Android 8, and I'm using the latest versions of the libraries. I will post the complete code for tests later. Perhaps I chose the too complicated Listener.

Comment: onNext is being called 1-3 times but your listener was called more times?

Comment: Listener dead and (of course) onNext.
Android 4.2 - all OK. Android 8 - :(
Native Listener working fine.
Full code here https://github.com/tim4dev/dirty_code/tree/master/Rx-Listener-to-Observable

Comment: Native phoneStateListener() working OK everywhere.
On Android 4.2 "Observable Listener" (Observable, Flowable) worked fine.
On Android 8.0 "Observable Listener" (Observable, Flowable) called 2--3 times and dead.
Steps to reproduce the problem:
- set PHONE_NUMBER to your own phone (yes, you will phone call to yourself)
- run app on Android 8
- call
- press disconnect (off hook)
- if you do it fast enough - everything will be ok
- if you listen to short beeps and wait, the Listener dies and does not react any more.

Comment: I'm not sure but, have you tried passing a different state to the `listen` method? check the changelog for 8.0 the API could have changed

Comment: Workaround (delete Listener, add polling :) https://gist.github.com/tim4dev/92bb22314c26ef16ddb055feb6e9858e